# How to make flat surface between two sculpted models?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I am making a 3D model of a car I designed ages ago. I used a sculpting tool to enhance the mesh that I increased the polygon level of and now, the edges where the windshield meets the body are seriously messed up (see picture below.) The windshield also has a rough edge. the surfaces are extremely thin so any time I try to use the flatten sculpting tool, it just makes it worse. What would be the best tool to make a completely flat surface on each that is flush between the two? Preferably a tool in edit mode so i have more control than I would with sculpting. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: If the surface is horizontal, I might try selecting everything and then scaling it to zero along one axis. This may or may not work…

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of curves moving along the X Y and Z axis.

Comment: That sounds like some thing that you should restart, unfortunately. I’ve run into this problem before when trying to use sculpting. Maybe try making a blocky base mash, and then using subdivision surface to round it out.